# ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy

I have two files: `test.py` and `test.kv`. When i call `insert_update_account()` function from the `.kv` file then it gives an error:

```
File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1144)
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 26, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__ref__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1043)
 ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists<br/>
```

If I comment the line `self.display_account()` in `insert_update_account()` function then there is no error.

## test.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.maximize()


con = lite.connect('test.db')
#con = lite.connect(path + 'fact.db')
con.text_factory = str
cur = con.cursor()

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):


    def display_account(self):
        self.dropdown.dismiss()
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rvaccount = TEST()
        self.content_area.add_widget(self.rvaccount)
        self.cur.close()
        self.con.close()

    def insert_update_account(self, obj):
        cur.execute("UPDATE table SET test1=?, test2=? WHERE test3=?",
                    (obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.col_data[0]))
        con.commit()
        self.display_account()


class TEST(BoxLayout):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    col1 = ListProperty()
    col2 = ListProperty()

    mode = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TEST, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.get_data()

    def update(self):
        self.col1 = [{'test1': str(x[0]), 'test2': str(x[1]), 'key': 'test1'} for x in self.data_items]
        self.col2 = [{'test1': str(x[0]), 'test2': str(x[1]), 'key': 'test2'} for x in self.data_items]


    def get_data(self):

        cur.execute("SELECT * from table")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        print(rows)
        i = 0
        for row in rows:
            self.data_items_city.append([row[0], row[1], i])
            i += 1
        print(self.data_items_city)
        self.update()

class TestApp(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return MainMenu()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: i think the problem you have lays in the `close()` you execute each time you display the account , and where is the `__init__` method in your class?

Comment: no init is fine since BoxLayout has an init.

Comment: @ddor254 i closed database connection every time after query executes but still showing error.

Comment: I guess you want to use something that is already removed in the insert_update_account method

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are mixing the cursor `cur` and connection `con` in your class `MainMenu`, since you've defined it in global scope, and are also using the same names within the scope of the class. As such, this could be happening because the variables have been mixed freely in your code.

You should try acquiring a connection and cursor explicitly within the MainMenu class. Something like below should make sure that you are acquiring a new connection every time, and that your code is not mixing the variables out of scope.

```
class MainMenu(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(self)
        self.con = lite.connect('test.db')
        self.cur = con.cursor()

    def display_account(self):
        self.dropdown.dismiss()
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.rvaccount = TEST()
        self.content_area.add_widget(self.rvaccount)
        self.cur.close()
        self.con.close()

    def insert_update_account(self, obj):
        self.cur.execute("UPDATE table SET test1=?, test2=? WHERE test3=?",
                    (obj.col_data[1], obj.col_data[2], obj.col_data[0]))
        self.con.commit()
        self.display_account()
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.But it gives error sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor